# Can I use the Facebook Graph API to retrieve updates each time a user comments on any object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

We are trying to retrieve as much data for an authenticated user as possible, but I don't see where there is a way to get updates whenever the user comments on an object (even if it isn't theirs).

I'm using the posts method on the API call, and I can see all the comments for posts initiated by my authenticated user. But I also want that feed to include all comments by the user as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can subscribe to Facebook events (such as when one of your application's user's comments on an object).  It's called "Real Time updates"  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/   Basically Facebook will call your (yep, it's a push model, you don't have to poll Facebook anymore) web app with update information based upon what your app has subscribed to.